# Adding 'cordova native storage' plugin to Ionic 1 App

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I need to allow users to store some basic settings for my app and read that Local Storage is now able to be deleted by iOS.

Research turned up this cordova plugin:

https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage

I have installed the plugin and adjusted my app to:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'ngCordova.plugins.nativeStorage'])
```

But I get:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngCordova.plugins.nativeStorage due to:
```

Is there another step I am missing?

Comment: I'm also trying to resolve this issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @pixeloft Nope, ended up using PouchDB which was probably the better option anyway.